# Google calendar API for PHP simple read-only request to get calendar events

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I'd like to write some simple PHP code for a website, to get read-only access to a public Google calendar list of events using Google's calendar API V3. I simply need to display a list of upcoming events from the calendar on a web page. I've read the developer docs and looked at the [**getting started section**](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) and the [**get events example code**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#examples) but I'm a bit confused. I'm wondering:

- Is there a simpler way to do what I need that avoids all this OAuth stuff? Is there a non-authenticated access method?
- If not, It looks like I need to set up access for my app at code.google.com/apis/console/, and then generate an ApplicationName, ClientID, ClientSecret, RedirectURI and a DeveloperKey. The **ApplicationName** and **DeveloperKey** are straightforward enough to find in Google Console. But for the other items I need to create an OAuth 2.0 ClientID, which requires me to choose if the Application Type is a Web Application or a Service Account. What should it be for my scenario? In this scenario no user login should be required, as I'm not requesting access to **their** calendar-- it's just a public calendar I need access to.
- What is the Redirect URI and how does it get used. How should I set it up?
- Google's API sample gets and caches an Access Token in Session data. Then the code comments say not to do this, that you should use a database instead. Seriously? Do I really need to deal with caching the access token? If so, is there a built-in DB caching mechanism in Google API or how do you handle this?

I'm really looking for a simpler approach. Your guidance would be welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're way overthinking this one.  If you just need access to events on a *public* calendar, then there's a way to do this without invoking the Google Calendar API and all of the attached complexity.  Every *public* Google Calendar has an iCal feed that can be viewed at a specific URL, usually in the form of:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/ical/{OWNER}/public/basic.ics
```

where `{OWNER}` is the URL-encoded email address of the owner of the calendar.

You can find the specific URL by viewing the calendar settings and scrolling to the bottom of the Calendar Details tab.

Comment: Charles, thanks for the response. I'm wondering if there is a drawback to using this approach, such as rate-limiting or rate-quota? I also see that I can get a JSON calendar feed with simple REST requests-- but I have the same question-- is it limited in some way? Otherwise, why would anyone use the OAuth technique just to get events from a public calendar? But that seems to be the only approach documented by Google.

Comment: I can't find any evidence of rate limiting for anything other than their official API.  Do keep in mind that at least for ICS, it's a complete dump of every single event on the calendar, so it can be rather chunky.  Even if there is no enforced rate limit, you surely don't want to be requesting it often.

Comment: I'm going to mark Charles' response as the answer because it will work, but I ended up using the Google V3 REST API here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list. 

That API returns JSON responses which are easy to parse with json_decode() in PHP. And, the query can be limited to dates you're interested in using query parameters. 

The calendar address can be found at the bottom of the Calendar Details tab under Setup just as Charles says. You also have to set up sharing so it's a public calendar for this to work.

Comment: I get "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"B0R-JqZ1uFKvtifdS4AVDz7BCB4/MTM4MDA5MjA0Nzc0ODAwMA\"",
   "id": "b698e22ed88877f4312afb473b9e9e43b5b2a18e",
   "status": 
   "updated"
   "start": 
   "end": 
   "iCalUID": in response. I need to read event title

Comment: In the google api console on https://code.google.com/apis/console under "services" it says: `Courtesy limit: 100,000 requests/day` for google calendar api

Answer (score 4):

Some tips to do this are embedded in the comments to Charles' answer. Anyway, as of 2014 (with Google Calendar v3 API), this is what I did: 
Go here to see how the v3 API works: 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it

Fill at least these three fields in the demo web form available on the above link:
`calendarId`: the URL-encoded email address of the owner of the calendar.
`timeMax`: End Time
`timeMin`: Start Time
(Use this Time Format: `2014-05-04T00:00:00-00:00` (Y-m-d T millisecond - offset))

You'll see the following REQUEST being sent out.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CALENDER_ID}/events?timeMax={start_time}&timeMin={end_time}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Now you can customize this request URL for your requirement and send regular GET requests from your code.

P.S -- To get your API Key, follow the procedure here: 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth