# Google Calendar API PHP | GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: file xxx.json does not exist

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I'm pretty new at this but I've been trying to use the google calendar API to show upcoming events on a website I'm making. So far I've enabled the API and created a service account to access the calendar. I've been using the instructions [from another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235850/google-calendar-api-v3-php-and-json/43596233#43596233) but I keep getting an error. I believe this is the code that is causing it:

```
//set environment variable to use your downloaded Service account key
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=myCredentials.json");
```

I have `myCredentials.json` in the same folder as the php file containing the above code. However when I test the code i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught DomainException: Unable to read the credential file specified by  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: file myCredentials.json does not exist
```

I'm not sure if I should be placing `myCredentials.json` in a different location or did I not specify the path correctly?

**Update:** I fixed it by using an absolute path. In my case I just had to prepend `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/` since I was using MAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the full path to the .json file when setting it as an environment variable.

You can verify that this is the problem by using `getenv()` function. You will notice the file is not found, but when you specify the absolute path it will find the file.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me get it.