# Using EventKit to read Google Calendar ical file

Tags: ios, swift, google-calendar-api, icalendar, eventkit

I have a public Google Calendar and I'm trying to integrate it into my App. Essentially I want the Google Cal to be a UI where users can update it and it would reflect in the App. 
I'm trying to figure out a way to best parse the Google Calendar. Things I'm thinking of:

1. Use the Google Calendar API- however is there a way to get the events in JSON format?
2. Using the public iCal link provided by Google Calendar- is it possible to parse this using EventKit ? If users update the Google Cal, will the iCal link also update ?

Any other suggestions would be amazing !

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/21555650/6143482

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate google calendar as you have described into an APP here i the documentation and example projects; https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

I am not sure why you need the events in JSON format. I integrated the calendar API into my IOS app without putting anything in JSON format.

Yes iCal will update (on Apple products it does)