# Export public Google Calendar events to csv (Python)

Tags: python, csv, google-calendar-api

There exists a public Google calendar whose calendar ID I have. I would like to set a start and end date and then get all the events between these dates in a CSV file. What is the most efficient way to do this in Python?

The closest solution I have found is https://stackoverflow.com/a/27213635/1936752 which yields a json file and does not have the filtering by date. I could do this with the json file and writing some code to filter only the dates I want and then export to csv, but I guess there is a smarter way?

The manual way of doing what I want is to download the ics file using the "Export Calendar" function and then using an ics to csv converted like https://openicsfile.com/csv-convert.html. I can then filter easily the dates I want. I wish to do exactly this but using a Python script.

Comment: For example, when "Events: list" is used, you can directly retrieve the events of specific dates. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) I thought that this might be useful for your situation. By the way, what values do you want to export from each event?

Comment: @Tanaike I only need the event name and date (they are all day events so time doesn't matter either). Thank you for the reference!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the events from a publicly shared Google Calendar.
- You want to retrieve the event title and the date as a CSV file.
- You want to achieve this using python.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, the event list is retrieved using ["Events: list" of Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) with API key. So, please retrieve your API key. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#create) And, please enable Calendar API at the API console.

And, please set the variables of the following sample script.

```py
import csv
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = "###" # Please set your API key.
calendar_id = "###" # Please set the calendar ID.
start = "2022-10-01T00:00:00Z" # Please set the start date you want to search.
end = "2022-10-31T00:00:00Z" # Please set the end date you want to search.

# Retrieve event list using googleapis for python.
service = build("calendar", "v3", developerKey=api_key)
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_id, timeMin=start, timeMax=end, fields="items(summary,start,end)", timeZone="UTC").execute()

# Retrieve the event title and date from all-day events.
allDayEvents = [["Event title", "Date"], *[[e.get("summary"), e.get("start").get("date")] for e in events_result.get("items", []) if e.get("start").get("date") and e.get("end").get("date")]]

# Output the retrieved values as a CSV file.
with open("sample.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerows(allDayEvents)
```

- When this script is run, the event list is retrieved from the publicly shared Google Calendar using an API key. And, a CSV file is created by including the event title and the date. In this sample, the all-day events from October 1, 2022 to October 31, 2022 are retrieved.
- You can see about the googleapis for python at [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python) and [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client).

#### References:

- [Authenticate using API keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys)
- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)

Comment: Thank you, your method is exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: @user1936752 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.