# Google Calendar API: How to create a "read-only" / non-editable event?

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to copy some events from my web app into a user's Google Calendar, with the catch that the events in the Google Calendar should not be editable once they're there (in particular, it should not be possible to change their time).  In other words, the Google Calendar is meant to be a read-only mirror of what's in my app.  I haven't been able to find any properties in the v3 API call that would make this possible; can I do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jim Unfortunately I think there is no features yet that support your request. Some work around is to [embed Google calendar to your web app](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en).

> 1. On a computer, open [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/). You can only get the code to embed in your website from a computer, not the mobile app.
>
>    2. In the top right, click Settings settings gear button > Settings.
>    3. Open the Calendars tab.
>    4. Click the name of the calendar you want to embed.
>    5. In the Embed This Calendar section, copy the iframe code displayed.
>    6. Open your website editor, then paste this code where you want the calendar to display
>
> **Note** : Your embedded calendar will only be visible to people you've shared it with. To allow all visitors to see your calendar, you'll need to make it public.

Another tip is to remove check the option for guest can modify on event.

You can get more information  from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086833/google-calendar-api-for-php-simple-read-only-request-to-get-calendar-events?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks -- this ("you cant do it") is increasingly my belief, as well.